# Programmatically setting UITabBarItem icons with StoryBoards?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I want to use a UITabBarSystemItem for the icon of one of my tabBarItem's but I'm using storyboards. I'm not sure where to set it. If I set it in the view's viewDidLoad then it doesn't change until you push the button in the tabBar. Before that it's just the blue ? square.

And as far as I know, you can't use UITabBarSystemItems  in IB inspector.

**UPDATE:**

Well first of all I'm an idiot. You can totally choose the icon in the IB Inspector.

Tab Bar Item -> Identifier -> Choose your icon.

But the question still remains how to do it programmatically. Or rather when/where?

Comment: You're not the only idiot :-). Thanks for pointing it out to another one, idiot that is.

Answer (score 11):

When using storyboards, a view controller initializes using the initWithCoder constructor so you could override that function and set the system item icon there like so

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) 
    {
        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Naturally, you can change the value of the system item to any of the values supported. Apple lists them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1)

Answer (score 7):

Check this code for your problem: Its working in my app.

```
- (NSArray *) initializeViewControllers
{
    NSArray *viewControllerArray = nil;
    viewController1 = <View Init Code>
    viewController2 = <View Init Code>
    viewController3 = <View Init Code>

    1stNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1]; 
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_home"];
    [1stNavController .tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Home" image:img tag:1];

    2ndNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2]; 
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_timeDrop"];
    [2ndNavController .tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Time Entry" image:img tag:2];

    3rdNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_invoiceSummary"];
    [3rdNavController.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Invoice Summary" image:img tag:3];

    viewControllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:1stNavController,2ndEntryNavController,3rdReportNavController, nil];
    return viewControllerArray;
}
```

This code is returning View Controllers with Images for their respective tabs. Here i used Navigation Controller inside the tabbar controller. you can also use view controller instead of navigation Controller.

Just add this code and initialize your tabbar controller as follows inside `appdidfinishlaunching` method:

```
 tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

_tabbarController.viewControllers = [self initializeViewControllers];

self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;
```

Hope it works.

Please reply.

Comment: This code is right, *IF* you're creating the ViewControllers and pushing them yourself. But the question is about Storyboards, so this answer is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Well that's quite simple!

For the where -> create a custom TabBarController (e.g. WBTabBarController).
In your StoryBoard explicitly set it.

For the how -> just overwrite viewDidLoad of the WBTabBarController and set your images for the TabBarItems. In the following example this was done using the NIKFontAwesomeIconFactory:

```
#import "WBTabBarController.h"
#import "NIKFontAwesomeIcon.h"
#import "NIKFontAwesomeIconFactory.h"
#import "NIKFontAwesomeIconFactory+iOS.h"

@interface WBTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation WBTabBarController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NIKFontAwesomeIconFactory *factory = [NIKFontAwesomeIconFactory tabBarItemIconFactory];

    UITabBarItem *item0 = self.tabBar.items[0];
    item0.image = [factory createImageForIcon:NIKFontAwesomeIconApple];

    UITabBarItem *item1 = self.tabBar.items[1];
    item1.image = [factory createImageForIcon:NIKFontAwesomeIconStackOverflow];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the initial scene of your storyboard is the tab bar view controller, you can access it in applicationDidFinishLaunching, it is the `rootViewController` of the app delegate's `window`. I don't know if you can swap in a system item if the bar item is already present, but you can definitely set the image and title.